# Constant Name Errors in IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm very new to Python, trying to learn. Seems like almost every cell of this code I copied has an error (for trading with Kalman filter). Can someone proofread? 
Source:
https://www.marketcalls.in/python/implementation-kalman-filter-estimation-mean-python-using-pykalman-bokeh-nsepy.html

I tried copying and running the code per the source but get error after error even when going cell by cell. I tried to update some code per Nsepy's documentation (get_price_history becomes get_history, stock becomes symbol) but I'm not getting very far.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

mids = (df.Open + df.Close)/2
spans = abs(df.Close-df.Open)

inc = df.Close > df.Open
dec = df.Open > df.Close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

output_notebook()

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000,      toolbar_location="left",y_axis_label = "Price",
      x_axis_label = "Date")

p.segment(df.date, df.High, df.date, df.Low, color="black")
p.rect(df.date[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color='green', line_color="green")
p.rect(df.date[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color='red', line_color="red")
p.line(df.date,state_means,line_width=1,line_color = 'blue',legend="Kalman filter")

p.title = "Implementation of Kalman Filter Estimation - TCS EOD chart"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
```

According to the source, I'd expect to run show(p) after the code above but get the name error "show' is not defined. If instead I run the code above without show(p), I get the name error "pd is not defined". Constant name errors.

Comment: Please tag *all* python related questions with the generic [python] tag

Comment: run `import pandas as pd` in very first cell.

Comment: Did you import all the libraries and modules as given in the link? More importantly are all of the libraries correctly set up in your system?

Comment: @krishna I did as suggested, ran entire code after running first cell code, and now it returns with NameError: name 'df' is not defined.

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta I am using IPython with Jupyter Notebook and have imported and checked installation in terminal for PyKalman, Bokeh, NSEPy and pandas. As far as being correctly set up - how might one check that?

Comment: Coded according to source: Cell 5: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0. Cell 6: NameError: name 'kf' is not defined. Cell 7: NameError: name 'state_means' is not defined. I have a display window below code with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

@Dawson, welcome to SO. When copying a piece of code from somewhere, make sure you understand fully what the code needs to run, and if you are new to a language, be sure you know what the codes does before running it. Now to your problem:
First:You should have all the libraries needed installed, e.g. pandas. That is done by running the following command in command line:

```
pip install pandas
```

as a side note, if they are installed and you want to upgrade them, you can use

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

you may need to do this for all the libraries in the first cell of the ipython notebook.

Then you should import those libraries to your notebook:

```
import pandas as pd # imports the library to your code under the name pd, from now on whenever you use pd.xxx the xxx function from the pandas library is called/executed.
```

These should make the problem go away.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, I added all modules as noted by original author and verified installation of them. Errors have not changed.

Comment: It works for me, with the changes you mentioned. Are you using a single notebook? and what are the error messages you get per cell?

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to run the code yourself. Yes, single notebook. I'll update with error messages when I get back from work. I'm thinking I must have a python2/python 3 pip/pip3 misconfiguration.

Comment: So I worked away the errors but there's no plot output. I have  'BokehJS 1.3.1 successfully loaded' before running 'Show(p)' and then a blank box with a legend on the left.

Comment: can you try this? 
    from bokeh.plotting import *
    output_notebook()
    p = figure()
    p.line([1,2,3], [2,1,3])
    show(p)

Comment: Ok looks like it works during certain times of day and only certain tickers.